# Handling branches in a top-down parser

Tags: compiler-construction, javacc

I have a top-down parser implemented in JavaCC.  So I'm leveraging the visitor pattern that is exposed to me for walking the AST.

If I ignore control flow, I've got the entire thing solved.  The issue I'm having with control flow is how to manage branches and where they point to.  Specifically, in IR generation, here's my case:

```
// This is just to make my example explicit.
honorary_source_statement()
if (expression()) {
    statements...
} else if(expression'()) {
    statements...'
} else {
    statements...''
}
// This just to make my example explicit.
honorary_sink_statement()
statements()...'''
```

I can tie my `honorary_source_statement()` to the leading `if`.  I can tie all the statements in the `if` statement where they need to go.  I can also tie all the subsequent branches together:

- `if`'s true goes to `statements...`
- `if`'s false goes to `else if`
- `else` if's true goes to `statements...'`
- `else if`'s false goes to `else`
- `else` goes to `statements...''`

The above works fine for n-nesting of if-statements.

The problem I'm having is taking the last instruction of `statements...`, `statements...'` and `statements...''` and tie that to the `honorary_sink_statement()`, their respective fall through.  I've read through the Appel book, the dragon book, and Louden book.  All of them just sort of hand wave and don't get into the details in managing that.

I'm building a hybrid IR.  So it's structural in that it is in graph form, and it uses a modified 3-address IR.

I've even tried to just just skip a step and use basic blocks to represent this, but the problem still persists: how do you tie the sink to the final fall-through instruction within a branch.

The relevant parts of my JavaCC are provided below.

```
void Statement() :
{}
{
    LOOKAHEAD(AssignmentInstruction())
    AssignmentInstruction()
    /* omitted rest of statements for brevity */
    |   BranchStatement()
    |   FunctionInvoke()
}

void BranchStatement() :
{}
{
    <IF> <LPAREN> Expression() <RPAREN> <LBRACE> Statement() <RBRACE>
    (<ELSE_IF> <LPAREN> Expression() <RPAREN> <LBRACE> Statement()<RBRACE>)*
    (<ELSE> <LBRACE> Statement() <RBRACE>)?
}
```

Which leaves me with a visitor structure:

```
 /**
  * f0 -> IfStatement()
  * f1 -> ( ElseIfStatement() )*
  * f2 -> ( ElseStatement() )?
  */
@Override
public BSVisitor visit(BranchInstruction n) {
    n.f0.accept(this);
    if(n.f1.present()) {
        n.f1.accept(this);
    }
    if(n.f2.present()) {
        n.f2.accept(this);
    }
}

/**
 * f0 -> <IF>
 * f1 -> <LPAREN>
 * f2 -> Expression()
 * f3 -> <RPAREN>
 * f4 -> <LBRACE>
 * f5 -> Statement()
 * f6 -> <RBRACE>
 */
@Override
public BSVisitor visit(IfStatement n) {
    // parse it!
}

/**
 * f0 -> <ELSE_IF>
 * f1 -> <LPAREN>
 * f2 -> Expression()
 * f3 -> <RPAREN>
 * f4 -> <LBRACE>
 * f5 -> Statement()
 * f6 -> <RBRACE>
 */
@Override
public BSVisitor visit(ElseIfStatement n) {
    // parse it!
}

/**
 * f0 -> <ELSE>
 * f1 -> <LBRACE>
 * f2 -> Statement()
 * f3 -> <RBRACE>
 */
@Override
public BSVisitor visit(ElseStatement n) {
    // parse it!
}
```

Comment: Surely the grammar rule for `BranchStatement` is not right.

Comment: Well I'd expect the rule to look something like this `<IF> <LPAREN> Expression() <RPAREN> <LBRACE> Statement() <RBRACE>
    (<ELSE_IF> <LPAREN> Expression() <RPAREN> <LBRACE> Statement()<RBRACE> )*
    ( <ELSE> <LBRACE> Statement() <RBRACE> )?`

Comment: Oops, I think I copied from the wrong file.  (I have my production set and a development set for me to goof around)  My production set is correct, and in line with what you have.  I've updated it accordingly.  My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the question exactly, but I'll try to answer it anyway.

First, I would build the AST a bit differently. It would be better if we represented, for example,

```
if( condition0 ) { statement1 }
elseif( condition1 ) {statement2}
elseif( condition2 ) { statement3 }
else { statement4 }
```

with a tree like this

```
 IF -+-- Condition0
     |
     +-- Statement1
     |
     +-- IF -+-- Condition1
             |
             +-- Statement2
             |
             +-- IF -+-- Condition2
                     |
                     +-- Statement3
                     |
                     +-- Statement4
```

If there is no ELSE, just make the final statement a SKIP statement, i.e. a statement that does nothing.

I'll assume your IR is some sort of control flow graph consisting of a bunch of nodes connected by a bunch of edges. It helps if edges can be created before their target nodes.

Now suppose that you have visitors for statements that take as input a set of edges (not yet targetted) and produce as output a set of edges (not yet targetted).  A visitor for a SKIP statement would take a set of edges and return the same set.  A visitor for an assignment statement would take a set of edges, produce a node, target all those edges to the node, then produce a single edge that leaves the node and output a set of containing just that edge.

Also suppose that the visitor for a Condition takes a set of not yet targetted edges and returns two sets of not yet targetted edges -- one for when the condition is true and one for when the condition is false.

The visitor for an IF looks like this

```
visit( IF(c, s, t), S)
    (A, B) := visit( c, S )
    T := visit(s, A )
    U := visit(t, B )
    output T union U
```

Your example code has three statements in a row, which you could represent in the AST using a sequential composition node that takes exactly 2 children like this

```
SEQCOMP -+-- statement0
         |
         +-- SEQCOMP -+-- statement1
                      |
                      +-- statement2
```

Then

```
visit( SEQCOMP(s, t), S)
    T := visit(s, S )
    U := visit(t, T )
    output U
```

Or you could represent a block of three statements with a single node with a variable number of children:

```
BLOCK -+-- statement0
       |
       +-- statement1
       |
       +-- statement2
```

And the visitor

```
visit( BLOCK( ss ), S)
    var T := S
    for t in ss
        T := visit(t, T )
    output T
```